# How to define a Stack Navigator in React-Native modal?

Tags: react-native, modal-dialog

I want to use a stack navigator inside my React-native modal. Is there any way to solve my problem ?

Comment: Why do you need to navigate inside a modal? It sounds like you should be using a regular screen for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your approach is wrong. You can add a new scene to your stackNavigator and set to mode:'modal' also headerShown: false with this props you can open a scene as a modal. Also with this method, you can use this scene as a custom modal and modify it.
Here is example:

```
<WorkFormNavigator.Navigator {...props} mode="modal">
  <WorkFormNavigator.Screen
    name={Modules.WorkForm.WorkForms}
    component={WorkForms}
    options={{title: ModuleScreenNames.WorkForms, headerShown: false}}
  />
```

If you mean to use the navigation in the modal (Navigation props) You can get the props and send them to your modal and now you can use them here.

```
const MyScene = ({navigation}) => {}
export default MyScene;
```